# Ошибки LNK2005, LNK1169. Что делать?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
Ошибка  6   error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > 
__cdecl GetValue(class 
std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::
char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?GetValue@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@0@Z)
 уже определен в core.obj   c:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RateMaker\RateMaker\main.obj   RateMaker

Ошибка  7   error LNK2005: "struct sHTTPBody * __cdecl sendHTTPmsg(struct sHTTPBody &,bool)" (?sendHTTPmsg@@YAPAUsHTTPBody@@AAU1@_N@Z)
 уже определен в core.obj   c:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RateMaker\RateMaker\main.obj   RateMaker

Ошибка  8   error LNK1169: обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более   
c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RateMaker\Debug\RateMaker.exe  RateMaker
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как Вы не привели никакого кода, то и ответ выглядит немного абстракным - [LNK2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72zdcz6f(v=vs.80).aspx). Там описано несколько случаев, когда ошибка возникает и как исправлять. LNK1169 возникает из-за LNK2005.

Мне кажется, что реализацию функции написали в h файле, а guard define забыли добавить.

Comment: core.h:
>#include <core.cpp>
>string GetValue(string src, string mask);
>sHTTPBody * sendHTTPmsg(sHTTPBody&msg, bool bLoadContent);

Comment: в h файле `include <core.cpp>` ??? Это уже логически коряво (хотя и допустимо).

Comment: Зачем вам в core.h инклудить core.cpp? Небось в core.cpp вы инклудите core.h. Получается циклическая зависимость - core.cpp подгружает core.h, который подгружает core.cpp, который подгружает core.h и т. д. Во-первых, уберите include <core.cpp> (почему в треугольных скобках, кстати? в кавычках же нужно), во-вторых, вставьте guard define, как вам советовал @KoVadim.